# vs 2010 increase memory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, out-of-memory

How can I start always Visual Studio 2010 with the 3g memory limit, i.e. like with this:

```
bcdedit /set increaseuserva 3072
```

Answer (score 2):

"How can I get the operating system started" would be the more typical question these days.  Video adapters eat up too much physical address space for this option to still work.  Get a 64-bit operating system and you'll have 4 gigabytes.  And editbin.exe /largeaddressaware on devenv.exe.  It voids the warranty I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set that limit, it is system-wide. It (your whole system) will always start with that limit. However, remember that while you use .NET, each single object cannot exceed 2GB.

For applications to work above the 2GB border, it is necessary that they have been compiled with the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag. Not sure if that flag was used for compiling Visual Studio itself, nor for the .NET Framework. If not, your system as a whole can consume more than 2GB, but applications that do not have that flag set, including Visual Studio, cannot exceed that limit for their own address space.

Comment: thanks Abel. if i understood your point is that in net we cannot go over 2gb , only apps compiled with that flag can do it?. I do have problems while compiling just the app in VS2010. outofmemory error. so i will be able to add the flag once i can compile at least.

Comment: @ramnz: It means that you need to set that flag to compile Visual Studio, because it is not your application, but VS that throws the OOM exception. But you cannot (re)compile VS. Hans Passant showed a possible way to hack your VS binaries. Even if that works (I doubt it), I wouldn't do it. What you need is a 64 bit OS, that's all (but even then: VS can only address max 4GB, possibly max 2GB, because VS itself is 32-bit).